# How to add the microsoft botbuilder framework node.js version 4 bot in microsoft teams?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I developed a bot using microsoft bot framework node.js sdk version 4. I deployed that bot in azure successfully and also test in web chat is working successfully. How to add that bot in microsoft teams? I tried to add teams by creating the manifest.json file for teams but it shows error.

Please tell how to add the bot in microsoft teams?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using App Studio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio) to create your manifest for you and load it into Teams. You'll also need to make sure that (1) sideloading is enabled for your organization and (2) the Teams channel is enabled on your bot in the Azure portal

Comment: thanks. I followed the above documentation that you given. But before install it shows "something went wrong". Where I missed?